# Как массово сделать UPDATE в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

В `$products` больше 10 тысяч записей, как можно оптимизировать UPDATE?

```
$products = [
  ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Заголовок', 'price' => 120],
  ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Заголовок 2', 'price' => 125],
  ...
];
foreach($products as $product){
  $db->query("UPDATE products SET price = '{$product['price']}' WHERE id = '{$product['id']}'");
}
```

Comment: @Jean-Claude, он больше 10 тысяч раз выполняется в цикле, это жестко

Comment: а что за задача решается? почему тут происходит 10000 запросов в цикле?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский обновление значения поля в таблице для всех записей по id

Comment: @SergeyFromPenza это я понял. но логика какова? почему 10000? это ведь не может происходить из корзины заказчика верно? значит это какая-то ещё задача. например импорта из другой бд. или подобное. почему нельзя это сделать силами SQL например. Полностью задача какая?

Comment: Обновление по API

Comment: Обновление происходит всех записей или частично? А то может проще сохранить и влить новый дамп?

Comment: НО пока всё равно не ясно....ну обновление по API и что.....что это значит

Comment: Одним запросом всю информацию для обновления слить во временную таблицу, вторым - выполнить обновление.

Comment: не ясно, чего вдруг голосуют за закрытие вопроса. Решение правда будет не оптимизация запросов, а отказ от него. Но в целом вопрос насущный и предельно понятный. Решение уже описано - вливаем во временную, и апдейт с джойном

Answer (score -2):

```
update products
set price = case
                when id = 1 then 120
                when id = 2 then 125
                else price
    end
    where id in (1, 2);
```

Comment: предлагаете 10тыс строк так писать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что вам мешает такой запрос сгенерировать средствами php?

Comment: Серьёзно думаете, что это хорошее решение? Это ужасное решение

Comment: @АлексейШиманский чем именно оно ужасное?

Comment: Ну например потому, что у всего есть лимиты, и  тот же IN принимает в себе не бесконечное число значений. как и условия when/then? Или например потому, что php упрётся в лимит памяти?

Comment: А может потому, что сам подход отстойный))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]